# How to list and record all network requests and response times in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am looking to convert all requests from `cy.intercept()` into `json` objects that include: `{'method':'____', 'url':'____', 'response_time':'____'}` so that they can be written to a `json` file for performance analysis.

I am currently able to show all of the request methods and URL's but not their response times.

Current code to get network requests:

```
cy.intercept({method:'GET', url:'**'}).as('gets');
cy.intercept({method:'POST', url:'**'}).as('posts');
cy.visit('url');
```

Is it possible to iterate through these individual requests with their response times and save them within an array?

I have tried saving the value returned from `intercept()` as a variable but it doesn't show all of the requests or their response times.

```
var gets = cy.intercept({method:'GET', url:'**'}).as('gets');
var posts = cy.intercept({method:'POST', url:'**'}).as('posts');
cy.visit('url');

cy.writefile('file1.json', gets);
cy.writefile('file2.json', posts);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `cy.intercept()` callbacks to get the duration.

The request callback fires when the request is intercepted, and the response callback is fired when the reponse returns.

```js
const gets = []

const logGet = (request) => {
  const start = Date.now()
  request.continue((response) => {
    const duration = Date.now() - start
    gets.push({url: request.url, duration})
  })
}

cy.intercept('*', logGet)

cy.intercept('**/tracking.min.js').as('done')           // last call I'm interested in

cy.visit('https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept')

cy.wait('@done').then(() => {                          // wait for last
  console.log(gets)
})
```

Also, chose a network request that marks the end on the stream. Cypress does not know when calls have ended, so you should `cy.wait()` on the last one instead of `wait(3000)`.

In above example, I chose the Cypress tracking script.

Answer (score 1):

To gain detailed information about the request and response including the response time, you can utilize the HAR file format (http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/).  To generate a HAR file on the fly during the execution of your Cypress tests you can use the [cypress-har-generator](https://github.com/NeuraLegion/cypress-har-generator).

```js
describe('my tests', () => {
  before(() => {
    // start recording
    cy.recordHar();
  });

  after(() => {
    // save the HAR file
    cy.saveHar({ waitForIdle: true });
  });

  it('does something', () => {
    cy.visit('https://example.com');

    // ...
  });
});
```

To obtain access to the HAR file within your tests, you can create a custom command for this purpose:

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

namespace Cypress {
  import { Har } from 'har-format';

  interface Chainable<Subject> {
    findHar(fileName?: string): Chainable<Har>;
  }
}

Cypress.Commands.add('findHar', (fileName?: string) =>
  cy
    .readFile(fileName ?? Cypress.spec.name.replace('.ts', '.har'))
    .then(data => cy.wrap<Har>(JSON.parse(data)))
);
```

Then, you can utilize it to iterate over the entries and map them to the desired structure:

```
cy.findHar()
  .its('log.entries')
  .then((entries: Entry[]) =>
    entries.map(({ request, time }: Entry) => ({
      response_time: time,
      method: request.method,
      url: request.url,
    }))
  );
```